# How to use special character in column name using HIVE JDBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I have a java program that is using Hortonworks' JDBC driver to connect to their database in the VirtualBox. Everything works very well, but I have problem with the colon in the sql query.

```
query = new StringBuilder("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS "+rowid+", * FROM "+tableName).toString();
```

The rowid I am trying to set is ":rowid:". I add colon in the front and in the back to make the column name to be unique for the other applications. Right now the colon has to be there and I want to know if there is a way to do it with Hortonworks JDBC Driver for Apache Hive (v1.0.36) from the official site. I have tested it without the colon there and that will work.

With the colon, the error message:

> JDBC driver version: HiveJDBC 01.00.36.1046
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]HiveJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 40000, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:30 cannot recognize input near 'AS' ':' 'rowid' in selection target:17:16, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:335, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:148, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:226, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:276, org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:468, org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementAsync:HiveSessionImpl.java:456, org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatementAsync:CLIService.java:298, org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:506, org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1317, org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1302, org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39, org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39, org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56, org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286, java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145, java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615, java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745, *org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 1:30 cannot recognize input near 'AS' ':' 'rowid' in selection target:22:6, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver:parse:ParseDriver.java:205, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver:parse:ParseDriver.java:166, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:437, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:320, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileInternal:Driver.java:1219, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileAndRespond:Driver.java:1213, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:146], sqlState:42000, errorCode:40000, errorMessage:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:30 cannot recognize input near 'AS' ':' 'rowid' in selection target), Query: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS :rowid:, * FROM input.
>       at com.simba.hiveserver2.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.executeStatementInternal(Unknown Source)
>       at com.simba.hiveserver2.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.simba.hiveserver2.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCNativeQueryExecutor.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>       at com.simba.hiveserver2.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCNativeQueryExecutor.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.simba.hiveserver2.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
>       at com.simba.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(Unknown Source)
>       at com.simba.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

Does anyone have any idea? I tried to add ' and \" in the string, but they all give errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special characters in column name should be enclosed by back-tick(`) character:

```
new StringBuilder("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as `"+rowid+"`, * FROM "+tableName).toString();
```

Read [Supporting Quoted Identifiers in Column Names](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6013) for more details.

Comment: thanks. this is closed, but I see Column Name as _c0 instead of :rowid: that I want. also in the data that now I retrieve from the result set it becomes 1:rowid: 2:rowid: 3:rowid:

Comment: sorry, maybe my question is confusing. I will try my best to explain what I want. The column name I want it to be is ":rowid:". There are colon in the front and in the back of the word rowid. The reason for that is to make it unique name so no other column can have the same name. The answer you provided will produce the column name as rowid without the colon that I want.

Comment: got it. try now, it should work. I have also added a page link which will help you to understand special characters behavior.

Comment: Hive throws this error from command line also for all identifier without back-tick. so i would suggest you to edit your question to make it more generic.